# Why does deficit of element in an initializer not generate error

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr

In this code, why do `b` or `b1` not trigger an error or even a warning (with -Wall -Wextra)

Probably it would be initialized with 0s implicitly, but shouldn't this be an error, especially with `constexpr`?

```
    constexpr std::array<int, 5> a{1,2,3,4,5};
    constexpr std::array<int, 5> b{1,2,3,4};    // no error
    constexpr int b1[100]{1,2,3,4};    // no error
    // constexpr std::array<int, 5> c{1,2,3,4,5,6}; error 5 vs 6
```

Comment: You would prefer having to type `constexpr int b1[100]{1,2,3,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};`?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm : I might not, but you definitely typed 96 0s there :P
Good point.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Thanks this answers my question, specifically [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3660859/2689696)